# convert byte to string represented with backslahes in python

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, byte, backslash

I have a python byte object like

```
a = b'1'
```

I want to convert to string like

```
"\\x31"
```

is there any easy way to do this?

Ultimately I have a byte object like

```
my_obj = b'\x00$\x00\x00\x001.1.0.00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001.1.0.21152\x00\x00'
```

and I want it to have a string with all chars backscaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = b'12'
s = "".join(f"\\x{abyte:02x}" for abyte in a)
# something like "\\x33\\x34"
```

I guess ... i still think you dont actually want to do this ...

if its just for readability then this is a good answer

```
import binascii
print(binascii.hexlify(a," ")) # something like "33 34"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The binascii did not work for me, I am getting 'module' object is not callable.

Comment: Oops ...it was late and I was tired